# How do I access json key in Angular 4.3 with the new HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angular, mongodb

I am trying to migrate from Angular 4.0 to 4.3 so I can upgrade step by step to Angular 5 or 6.

I developed a simple authentication that uses `jwt` for every request. The `jwt` is stored in a local storage.

I just knew that 4.3 version now uses `HttpClientModule` that will be declared to

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [
HttpClientModule,
]
```

I am using a service for my authentication, registering user and for loading the token.

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authToken: any; // class property so we can access it anywhere
  user: any;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers})
  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {
    // code for storing user data
  }

  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(
    private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoginSubmit() {

    const user = { 
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      // console.log(data);

      if(data.success) {
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.router.navigate(['admin']); //redirect
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']); //redirect
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I am prompted with an error above in login.component.ts file.

> login.component.ts (43,15): Property 'success' does not exist on type
>   'Object'.

I tried to print `data` in console and this is what I see:

```
{success: true, token: "JWT dlskdlskdlskdlsdklgfdg;kfd;gkd;432ks;dfks;fks;fkds;f", user: {…}}
success: true
token:"JWT dlskdlskdlskdlsdklgfdg;kfd;gkd;432ks;dfks;fks;fkds;f"
user:{id: "95430590435934fkdlkfldskfds", name: "Carlo K", username: "carlok", email: "carlok@gmail.com"}
```

Do you know how can I access `data` from the console.log above?

I want to use `data` like this in login.component.ts:

```
if(data.success) {
// do code
}
```

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

`Note`: I don't encounter an error above if i use the Angular 4.0 -- `HttpModule` in app.module.ts and the `Http` Object

Comment: Change `.subscribe(data => {` to `.subscribe(data:any => {` or alternately, you can change `authenticateUser(user) ` to `authenticateUser(user): Observable<any>`

Comment: Try: subscribe(data => { if(data){ if(data.success){}}}

Comment: @user184994 thanksf or the quick response but no luck..

Comment: @PrashantPimpale error is still the same..

Comment: With the same error? Would you mind updating the question with what you tried, because that should prevent that error by removing type checking for that value

Comment: @ConanCarroll that is list I think, is it?

Comment: @user184994 I used your answer this.authService.authenticateUser(user): Observable<any>.subscribe(data => {} but I am prompted with Cannot find name 'Observable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new `HttpClientModule` would prefer you to provide a `return type / interface` for your http call. Any call that do not have `type` specify, will be cast to `Object`. That mean, to solve your issue, you can either of the below approach, option 3 preferred (best practise).

1. Provide `any` type, change this line from `return this.http.post(...)` to `return this.http.post<any>(...)`.
2. Provide `any` type, change this line from 
   `this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => ...` to `this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data: any => ...`.
3. Strong type it. Eg. Create an interface and use it. `interface Data { success: boolean; token: string; user: any; }`. Change this line from `return this.http.post(...)` to `return this.http.post<any>(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I go on with option 3, where should I create the interface in login.component file or the auth.service.ts file?

Comment: It depends on your project structure. Normally, in my project, I setup a folder to hold all interfaces and classes ts file. Name the folder as `models` (as in data model) or `interfaces`. It's up to you. :)

Comment: I see. Thank you @Chybie You are great.